# SystemParametersInfo sets wallpaper completly black (using SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER)

Tags: c++, winapi, desktop-wallpaper

I try to change my desktop wallpaper. It works just fine when I use it like this:

```
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, "C:\\1.jpg", SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
```

But when I use it like this, the desktop wallpaper is set completly black:

```
std::string s = "C:\\1.jpg";
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, &s, SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
```

I tried to get some more info via using `GetLastError()`, but the return value is just 0. I also tried to use .png-files, but this doesn't change anything.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, (void*)s.c_str(), SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
```

The `SystemParametersInfo` function doesn't accept `std::string` pointer as path, it accepts a null-terminated char array. Which is what the `c_str()` method of `std::string` provides.

Comment: windows api are only compatible with C language type system and interface?

Comment: almost the solution. I tried to use c_str(), but it says it can't convert from "const char *" to "PVOID" But it works fine if you use it like this: `(void*)s.c_str()`. Thx :)

Comment: @AngelusMortis wrong conclusion; rather the Windows API is only compatible with C strings, not C++ `<string>` objects

Comment: @andlabs: Angelus's conclusion was not wrong. The Win32 API is designed for C.  Any C-compatible language can use it. it makes very few accommodations for C++.

Comment: @RemyLebeau right; perhaps I misinterpreted the statement then

Comment: You do not need the cast to `void*` here. Calling the `c_str()` member function is enough. Eschew casts whenever possible.

Comment: @CodyGray: no, you do need the cast, it's needed to drop the `const` modifier. You can, however, cast to `char*` rather than `void*`.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using **"C:\\1.jpg"**, use **@"C:\1.jpg"**. This resolves the issue.

Comment: No chance it changes anything.