# How can I load a image resource? I want to make an app that changes the Windows background

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

So I want to make a GUI app where a person can choose between 2 background options: IDR_BACKGROUND1, and IDR_BACKGROUND2(that's how they are defined in Resource.h). How can I load the resources in code?
I believe that syntax for changing the background is :

```
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, (here comes the path for 
    image), SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
```

but as I said, I don't know how to do it. Pls help :))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SystemParametersInfo sets wallpaper completly black (using SPI\_SETDESKWALLPAPER)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34710677/systemparametersinfo-sets-wallpaper-completly-black-using-spi-setdeskwallpaper) It shows you how to correctly use `SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,...)`.

Comment: The thing is that I don't know how to use a embedded resource, like IDR_BACKGROUND1.

Comment: The documentation tells you that the file is from disk, not an embedded resource. Extract the resource to a disk file, and then set that file as the wallpaper.

Comment: oh, right. Thanks =)